# Are these two meanings of a pull request both correct, and contrary to each other?

Tags: github, pull-request

On my local repository, I created a branch A from branch B. I did some work on branch A, and pushed A to github.

Then I created a pull request on github, in order to merge branch A into  branch B, I heard that it is said to be "branch A is pulled from branch B".  Is it correct?

Doesn't a pull request mean merging branch A into branch B?

What does  "pulling" branch A from branch B mean?

It seems to me that the two meanings of a pull request are contrary to each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you merge `A` into `B` it will be:

> Branch A is pulled into B.

or

> Branch B is pulled from A.

It refers to the branch you're currently at. If you're in branch B and pull from A, that pull will first fetch A and then merge A.

Comment: Thanks. See my edit for the meaning of branch A and branch B.

Answer (score 1):

Pull and Merge are two different process.

"branch A pull from branch B" means you make a editable copy, call it A, from B (If A originally not exist).

"Merge A into B" means you are applying all the changes you made in A back into B

the reason people saying that "branch A is pulled from branch B" is because if A is not pull from B, it can not be merged back to B

Comment: Thanks. See my edit for the meaning of branch A and branch B.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different uses of 'pull' in git terminology and, while not contradictory, they can be confusing at first.

### 1. Pull:

From the command-line command `git pull` (also known as a combination of `fetch` and `merge`). Essentially just gets the remote code (or 'pulls' it to your computer) and merges it into your local code. Read more [here](https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/).

### 2. Pull request:

When you want to merge your changes into the repo. Generally opens a discussion and review of your changes before the pull request (or 'PR') is accepted. Read more [here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/).

---

As an aside, there is also a 'push' command, which may make things clearer (and reiterate the direction pushing and pulling to and from local and remote repos). `git push` 'pushes' your commits from local to remote (i.e. the opposite of #1, `git pull`). Read more [here](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/).